# ExtJS 4 smartphone size

Tags: extjs

I had very simple appication written for old (24x80) terminals
working in production company. My client ask me to transfer it 
as a web application and I use ExtJS 4 to do it. It looks like 
this:

[image]

[image]

and its working on pc stations without any problem.

But next question of my client is to modify this application to
work also on tablets and smartphones. And only problem we see
is proportion, on smartphone this screens are to small. What is
the best way to do it? How can I resize fields and fonts and buttons depending on screen size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a Responsive Application.
The problem is that the responsiveConfig was introduced in [ExtJS 5](https://www.sencha.com/blog/designing-responsive-applications-with-ext-js/).

So if you cannot move to extjs 5.0 or above take a look at [this answer](https://www.sencha.com/blog/designing-responsive-applications-with-ext-js/).

Another aproach is to use multiple instances for the view. Create three different view instances, one for desktop, one for tablet and one for mobile, keep the same Controller, Model, Store etc and when you initialize your application display the correct view according to the screen size.

Comment: If you are going to migrate to a newer version why don't you move to 6.x? Also if your views are simple the approach with the three views would be easy. Good luck Tad.